# Element not found -Selenium -Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I try access to results home of Manchester United but impossible to access.
.[Here is the website page](https://www.flashscore.com/team/manchester-united/ppjDR086/results/)

And here is below a piece of code HTML the page:

```
<div id="g_1_l2dtbMED" title="Click for match detail!" class="event__match event__match--static event__match--last event__match--oneLine"><div class="event__time">04.10. 17:30</div><div class="event__participant event__participant--home"><svg class="card___2ip_DLm icon--redCard icon--redCard-first icon--redCard-last"><title></title><use xlink:href="/res/_fs/build/symbols.f1bc6b2.svg#card"></use></svg>Manchester Utd</div><div class="event__scores fontBold"><span>1</span>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<span>6</span></div><div class="event__participant event__participant--away fontBold">Tottenham</div><div class="event__part">(1&nbsp;-&nbsp;4)</div><span class="wld wld--l" title="Loss">L</span></div>
```

The results that I to search parse is 'L' and is located in balise `<span>`.

Here is the code that I did for try parse it:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.flashscore.com/team/manchester-united/ppjDR086/results/"
driver.get(url)

Team = 'manchester Utd'
results = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.find_elements((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='event__participant--home' and contains(text(),'"+ Team +"')]//ancestor::div/span")))
print(len(results))
```

But this cast me exception 'TimeoutException' after 20s that is time limit of search.

Comment: //div[@class='event__participant--home'] typo?

Comment: No, it's done on purpose because the result must be the brother of balise that contained this name class and the text 'Team'. it must fill double condition. This not function find_elements() that I use but visibility_of_element_located()

Comment: 'manchester Utd' should be 'Manchester Utd'

Comment: also find_elements should be an expected conditions.

Comment: The name of club is typos but what do you want say for 'should be an excepted conditions'

Comment: EC.presence_of_all_elements_located the condition for what you are waiting for,

Comment: Thank you, this is the function we are looking for.

Comment: Also the below grabs both the home and away team with the Manchester Utd.

Comment: Yes, Yes, it's true, me I want only the results away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locator you are looking for is

```
//div[contains(@class,'event__participant--home')][text()='Manchester Utd']//following-sibling::span[1]
^ find a DIV that contains the class indicating a home game
                                                  ^ that also contains the team name
                                                                           ^ then find the first sibling SPAN that follows
```

That locator will find the elements that contain L, W, D, etc. for only the home games.

If you are going to wait for the elements, you will want to wait for *visible*, not *presence*. Presence is when the element is just in the DOM but not necessarily visible. If you are going to scrape text off the page, you need to wait for visible. You can do that using `EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located()`. See [the docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located). If you try to scrape the page when they are present but not visible, it will throw an exception.

Your updated code is below

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.flashscore.com/team/manchester-united/ppjDR086/results/"
driver.get(url)

Team = 'Manchester Utd'
results = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class,'event__participant--home')][text()='" + Team + "']//following-sibling::span[1]")))
print(len(results))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this xpath-

```
//div[contains(text(),'Manchester Utd')]/following-sibling::span
```

Comment: Excuse me this do not solve my problem because this code takes all results of Man.utd . Result both away and at home.